# Defining a bijective function from $2\mathbb{N}$ to $3\mathbb{Z}-1$?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$2\mathbb{N}=\{2n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}-1=\{3n-1:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Work: So far, my plan is to first define a bijective function from $2\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ and then define another bijective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $3\mathbb{Z}-1$.

$f:2\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is defined by $f(n)=\frac{n}{2}$

I then proved that this is both injective and surjective.

However, I have trouble defining a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $3\mathbb{Z}-1$.

A function that I did come up with, although I am not sure if it works, is $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow 3\mathbb{Z}-1$ defined as $g(n)=3\frac{n}{2}-1:2|n$ and $g(n)=\frac{-3(n-1)}{2}-1:2\nmid n$

Comment: Hint: You also have a bijection between $3\mathbb{Z} - 1$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, so try to find a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$. Now, maybe by part, if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is even, ..., otherwise, ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a two-step plan for finding a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $3\mathbb Z - 1$, which you have implemented:

1. Find a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Z$ (this is the hard part!).
2. Find a bijection from $\mathbb Z$ to $3\mathbb Z - 1$.

Your function works if you replace $n\mid 2$ with $2\mid n$ (and $n\nmid 2$ with $2\nmid n$) and if you assume $0\notin\mathbb N$ (conventions vary on this point.)

Comment: Awesome thanks. Also I fixed the $n|2$.